# c++ map inside map - delete pointer

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem I can't seem to solve.
I have a map inside another map which holds 2 pointers.

```
std::map<std::string,std::map<sf::SoundBuffer*,sf::Sound*>> listSound;
```

When I try the following code to free the allocated memory i get the following error: **map/set iterator not incrementable**

Its a debug assertion fail as stated before and is thrown on line 262 in Visual studio\11.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtree This happens when i close down the program as expected.

This is the code in the destructor:

```
~AudioManager()
{
    typedef std::map<sf::SoundBuffer*, sf::Sound*> typeInnerMap;
    typedef std::map<std::string, typeInnerMap> typeOuterMap;
    typedef typeInnerMap::iterator inner_iter_t;
    typedef typeOuterMap::iterator outer_iter_t;

    for (outer_iter_t o = listSound.begin(); o != listSound.end(); ++o)
    {
        for (inner_iter_t i = o->second.begin(); i != o->second.end(); i++)
        {
            delete i->first;
            delete i->second;
        }
    }

}
```

This is how i insert a value:

```
sf::SoundBuffer* soundbuffer = new sf::SoundBuffer();
soundbuffer->loadFromFile(_file);
sf::Sound* sound = new sf::Sound(*soundbuffer);
typedef std::map<sf::SoundBuffer*, sf::Sound*> mapType;
listSound[_file].insert(mapType::value_type(soundbuffer, sound));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: SOLVED.

Problem is, I tried to delete SoundBuffer before deleting sound which depends on the soundbuffer to begin with:

So this works:
                delete i->second;
                delete i->first;

Comment: Are you getting a *compiler* error? Or a runtime crash/exception?

Comment: @"Joachim Pileborg" This error usually occurs when debugging. Its an assertion

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Using raw pointers.

Comment: it compiled and worked for me, is this the real code you are having problem with?

Comment: Its a runtime error mate and n.m. raw pointers is all good and still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I've tried to recreate the problem, but it all works fine, with valgrind reporting no leaks either. What compiler are you using? Where does the debugger say the error occurs?

Comment: "i get the follwing error" - how and where? What compiler/library/versions?

Comment: Its a debug assertion fail as stated before and is throwned on line 262 in Visual studio\11.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtree

This happens when i close down the program as expected.

Comment: @basdbfnsa “n.m.” is very right, you know. You are not supposed to use these `sf::` classes via pointers, you should use them by value. In fact, these classes *already* encapsulate the raw pointers for you, and manage their memory.

Comment: @basdbfnsa Can you edit the information into the question? For now I can only assume [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) invoked elsewhere.

Comment: You have UB somewhere else. The problem is not in this code. VTC due to no repro. Debug it down to a _testcase_.

Comment: And, no, raw pointers are _not_ "all good". In particular, `new sf::Sound(*soundbuffer);` is concerning.

Comment: Why is that? kindly explain what the problem is, the sound is playing, everything is working except deleting the data. Also swalog managed to recreate the problem. So what is going on under the hood that creates this problem. Just blaming raw pointers and "get on with your life" is not a good answer nor solves the problem

Comment: No, blaming raw pointers doesn't solve the problem. Excluding them from your code might.

Comment: "everything is working except deleting the data". That's the hard part.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, I tried to delete SoundBuffer before deleting sound which depends on the soundbuffer to begin with:

So this works: delete i->second; delete i->first;

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer - it was helpful for me!